# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, strftime

Not exactly sure why this is happening, but Im receiving the following error. All I'm trying to do is display the dates and times from my database. When I remove `('%I:%M %p')`from `strftime`, everything works fine, but, obviously, the dates/times no longer display. Not sure what's going wrong, or what I'm missing. TIA.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'strftime'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/Desktop/BlueSkyAdmin/app/routes.py", line 81, in view_tour
return render_template('view-tour.html', title='View Tour', tour=tour, user=user)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
ctx.app,
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/Desktop/BlueSkyAdmin/app/templates/view-tour.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html" %}
File "/Users/brandoncarr/Desktop/BlueSkyAdmin/app/templates/base.html", line 383, in top-level template code
{% block base %}{% endblock %}
File "/Users/brandoncarr/Desktop/BlueSkyAdmin/app/templates/view-tour.html", line 143, in block "base"
<p style="bottom: 0;">Created by <strong>{{ tour.author.first_name }} {{ tour.author.last_name }}</strong> at {{ tour.timestamp.strftime('%I:%M %p') }}</p>
```

models.py:

```
class Tours(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_fname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_lname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_phone = db.Column(db.String(140))
    partner_fname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    partner_lname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    partner_phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    region = db.Column(db.String(140))
    tour_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    tour_time = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    gift = db.Column(db.String())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self):
        return '<Tours {}>'.format(self.customer_fname, self.customer_lname, self.customer_phone, 
        self.partner_fname, self.partner_lname, self.partner_phone, self.region, self.tour_date, 
        self.tour_time, self.gift, self.timestamp)
```

forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password_repeat = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register Now')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')

class ToursForm(FlaskForm):
    customer_fname = StringField('Customer First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_lname = StringField('Customer Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_fname = StringField('Partner First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_lname = StringField('Partner Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    tour_date = DateField('Tour Date', format='%m-%d-%yyyy')
    tour_time = DateTimeField('Tour Time', format='%I:%M %p')
    gift = SelectField('Gift Selected', choices=[('Cruise', 'Cruise'), ('Hotel Suite', 'Hotel Suite'), ('Airfare', 'Airfare'), ('Safari', 'Safari')])
    region = SelectField('Region', choices=[('Select Region', 'Select Region'), ('Oceanside', 'Oceanside'), ('Scottsdale', 'Scottsdale'), ('Granite Bay', 'Granite Bay'), ('Laguna Hills', 'Laguna Hills')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Tour')
```

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/tours/<int:id>/view')
@login_required
def view_tour(id):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    tour = Tours.query.get_or_404(id)
    user = User(first_name=form.first_name.data, last_name=form.last_name.data, 
    email=form.email.data)
    return render_template('view-tour.html', title='View Tour', tour=tour, user=user)
```

The code from my HTML file throwing the error:

```
{{ tour.timestamp.strftime('%I:%M %p') }}
```

Thanks again!

UPDATE:

Looks like my models were missing the `default=datetime.utcnow` on the tour_time and timestamp. I forgot to migrate my db after removing them. Everything started working again.

Comment: in the `routes.py`, `view_tour` function, can you print and check if you are getting value for `tour`.

Comment: timestamp seems to be None. Thats why you are not getting this error. Try printing the value of tour.timestamp in routes.py and check if its None or  have some value.

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake. Make sure your DateTime fields in your models.py are using the `default=datetime.utcnow`. Thanks for the comments.